# Using cookies to transfer numeric variables

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is my code:

```
var j = 0;
var c = 0;
var riepvet = new Array();

function controllo() {

    if ((src1 == "") || (src1 == "undefined")) {
        alert("Selezionare un'immagine.");
    }
    else if(j==0) {
        riepvet[c] = src1;
        c++;
        for (var k = 0; k < c; k++) {
            alert(riepvet[k]);
        }
        location.href = "schienale.html";
        j++;

    }
    else if (j==1){
        riepvet[c] = src1;
        c++;
        for (k = 0; k < c; k++) {
            alert(riepvet[k]);
        }
        location.href = "riep.html";
        j++;
    }
}
```

What I need, is make the numeric variables `j` and `c` available through all the pages of my program. Is this possible using cookies (since they aren't string but numbers)?

I've already tried to use `eval()` but it seems not to work.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
 Cookies.set('j', 0);
var j = parseInt(Cookies.get('j'));

Cookies.set('imuno');
var imuno = Cookies.get('imuno');
Cookies.set('imdue');
var imdue = Cookies.get('imdue');

function controllo() {

    if ((src1 == "") || (src1 == "undefined")) {
        alert("Selezionare un'immagine.");
    }
    else if (j == 0) {
        imuno = src1;
        Cookies.set('imuno', src1);
        alert(imuno);
        location.href = "schienale.html";
        j++;
        Cookies.set('j', 1);

    }
    else if (j == 1) {
        imdue = src1;
        Cookies.set('imdue', src1);
        alert(imuno,imdue);
        location.href = "riep.html";
        j++;
        Cookies.set('j', 2);
    }
}
```

When i retrieve the function `Controllo()` the variable `j`does not mantain the value.

Comment: *"since they aren't string but numbers"* - Numbers *can* be formatted as strings. And later turned back into numbers...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use cookies, i suggest [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

- Create a cookie :

  ```
  Cookies.set('name', 'value');
  ```
- Read cookie :

  ```
  Cookies.get('name'); // => 'value'
  ```

You could store you numbers as strings then cast them after `get`, e.g:

```
Cookies.set('j', j);  //Set j
j = parseInt( Cookies.get('j') );  //Get j
```

Example :

```
Cookies.set('j', 1); //Set j
var j = parseInt( Cookies.get('j') );  //Get j

if( j == 0 ){
    alert('Yes j == 0');
}else{
    alert('No j == '+j);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Just few questions: once i create the cookie can i use just the variable to do for example comparisons? (if(j == 0) or j++)? If yes, when a variable increases, does the cookie update the new value? Hope i explaned well, im new to this :)

Comment: Yes, if you're using `parseInt` like mentioned in my post.

Comment: Can u give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Last question, if I increase a variable (like j++), does the cookie update itself to the new value?

Comment: No, it's not you should update the cookies using `set`, Cookies.set('j', new_value).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104524/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-francesco-monti).

Answer (score 1):

Are many ways to achieve that .

You can use cookies

Use a cookie for each key-value you want to store:

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=myValue";
document.cookie = "myOtherCookie=myOtherValue";
```

Store a single cookie with a custom serialization of your complex data, for example JSON:

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=" + JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar', baz: 'bar'});
```

or

you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
localStorage.setItem('myvariable', 'myvalue');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i dont know JSON, can i proceed anyway?